# Template class assignment between different types

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a struct (`School`) templated with a type T. The type T will be user defined types. One of the type (`CoedSystem`) will not be visible to the program as it is exported as a handle by the library. Other type (`Coed`) is defined in the program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

template<typename T>
struct School
{
    T var1;
    T var2;
    T var3;
    T var4;
    T var5;
    T var6;
    int otherData;
};

typedef unsigned int CoedSystem;  //this type is like a handle to hidden class

class Coed
{
    CoedSystem m_schoolSystem;
    int        m_yearEstablished;
public:
    Coed& operator=(const CoedSystem& other)
    {
       this->m_schoolSystem = other;
       this->m_yearEstablished = 2020;
       return *this;
    }
};  

int main()
{
    School<Coed> coedSchool;
    School<CoedSystem> coedSchool2;
    coedSchool2 = coedSchool;
}
```

Question:
How can I get the assignment coedSchool2= coedSchool, to work.
Constraints:
I want to achieve this with minimal key strokes. The number of variables in `School` will be double digit. An explicit assignment operation in `School` class copy assignment operator would be the easiest choice but also the lengthiest. Any suggestions? I am looking for something like metaprogramming, where compiler would look at `Coed::operator=(const CoedSystem&)` and will use it to do the full `School` structure conversion by itself.

Edited this article to republish the question. Previous question had lot of typo and I have fixed them in this edition.

Thanks

Comment: `Coed& operator=(const BoysOnly& other)` and `Coed& operator=(const GirlsOnly& other)` are exactly the same function since `BoysOnly` and `GirlsOnly` are the same type.  If you want differing types, then make those `structs`, i.e. `struct BoysOnly {int value; }; struct GirlsOnly { int value; };`

Comment: There are a number of typos in your code snippet. Also, `BoysOnly` should be a type, and it should be different from `GirslOnly`. Here's what a [mre] would [look](https://godbolt.org/z/75G7vh) like.

Comment: You defined `operator=` for `Coed`, but `coedSchool = boysSchool;` would call `School`'s `operator=`. Right now it's not clear what you actually want to do. Also what's a handle to a hidden class? I would interpret it as a class where you know only the declaration, but not the definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a templated copy assignment operator for `School` like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct School
{
    // ... members
    
    template <typename U>
    School& operator=(School<U> const & s) 
    { 
        // do copy assignment
        return *this; 
    }
};
```